# Joining tables in sequelize js (Many to Many)

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a query that retrieves all rows from table A and for each of them also retrieves all the associated rows from table B. The associated indexes of tableB are stored in one of the cells in each row of tableA.

```
Table A
+----+------------+----------+
| id |   Mention  | relation |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | book       | 1;2      |
|  2 | magazine a | 1        |
|  3 | magazine v | 2;3      |
+----+------------+----------+

table B
+----+----------+
| id |     name |
+----+----------+
|  1 | project 1|
|  2 | project 2|
|  3 | project 3|
+----+----------+
```

I tried retrieving them by nested queries, something along these lines:

```
                TableA.findAll().then((mentions) => {

                    if (mentions !== null) {

                        for (const mention of mentions) {
                            const projectIds = mention.relation.split(';')
                            
                            var projectArr = []
                            tableB.findAll({
                                    where: {
                                        id: projectIds
                                        }
                                    }).then((data) => {
                                    for (const project of data) {
                                        projectArr.push(project.dataValues)
                                    }

                                    mention.mentionProjects = projectArr
                                    mention.dataValues.mentionProjectsId = projectIds 
                                    
                                })
                        }
                        
                        return mentions
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        res.json({message: 'no mentions exist'})
                    }
                }).then((mentions) => {
                    res.json(mentions)
                })
```

When I do exactly the same query for one row of table A it works like charm as I send the res.json(mentions) after the inner query promise is resolved. In this case however it doesn't work and the resulting data in mentions are equal to the first query (the new properties are not added, even though they are when I log them after the inner query finishes). However, when I add the property directly (not within another query) it works. So basically it is a problem of synchronisation. The question is, why does it behave like this? I thought that by sending the res.json after the promise of findAll function is fulfilled it should wait for the inner query to finish? How would you solve this using async?

I tried to avoid using include clause because frankly I am quite new to SQL. However I am already here so let's ask. Would it would be more efficient to create an intermidiary table between the two tables like this instead of using two separate queries:

```
+-------+------+
| idA   | idB  |
+-------+------+
|  1    | 1    |
|  1    | 2    |
|  2    | 1    |
|  3    | 2    |
|  3    | 3    |
+-------+------+
```

In this case, my question is: How would the include clause and the relationship between the tables look like? I successfully managed to include another table with direct association using foreign key but I never needed to use an intermidiary table before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your `projectIds` variable is an **array** of the id strings, but your `where` clause cannot work with that. You could set up an `IN` clause in the query, using the `projectIds` array to construct the `IN` value set.

Comment: But it does work when I do the exact same thing with a single row?

Comment: The newfound objects are added to the projectArr and then to mention.mentionProjects. The problem is they are not accessible outside the inner query function. From within I can log them and they are there as they should. Unfortunately I need to wait for each row to be processed so I cannot send result from within

Comment: That's not the way to make a one-to-many/many-to-one schema anyway. Your table B needs the table A id, so then you can join from table A to table B where the A id in table B equals the A id in the A row. In other words, every row of table B has the id of the table A row that it goes with. Jamming multiple keys into a single column is kind-of a mess, and it means you'll be doing way too many queries.

Comment: So basically the second part of the question where I ask about intermediary table is the right way to go? I cannot afford to repeat entries in neither table A nor table B as I also use both of them separately

Comment: Would you please show me how would the include clause look like in order to access data from tableB using table C as intermediary?

Comment: You don't need a third table; that's only necessary for many-to-many relationships. If you have many entries in B for a single row of A, and every B row can only be part of one A, then that's one-to-many/many-to-one (depending on the direction you're thinking about it).  For many-to-many, then yes you do need a third table, each row of which being an id for A and an id for B (single id values, not lists). With two `belongsToMany()` declarations, one for a and one for B, with the same "through" table, Sequelize will set up the schema for you if you want.

Comment: You are right I guess I am looking for many to many relation (mentions can have multiple projects and projects can have multiple mentions) even though I plan to access it only through one side (mention -> projects) thus my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the situation where "*mentions can have multiple projects and projects can have multiple mentions*" then a **junction table** (project_mentions) is a practical solution. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE projects (     -- becomes model "Project"
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE mentions (     -- becomes model "Mention"
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    mention TEXT NOT NULL,
    relation TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE project_mentions (     -- becomes model "ProjectMention"
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    projectid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    mentionid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (projectid) REFERENCES projects(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (mentionid) REFERENCES mentions(id)
);
```

data:

```
INSERT INTO projects (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'project 1'),(2, 'project 2'),(3, 'project 3');

INSERT INTO mentions (id, mention, relation)
VALUES (1, 'book', '1,2'),(2, 'magazine a', '1'),(3, 'magazine v', '2,3');

INSERT INTO project_mentions (id, projectid, mentionid)
VALUES (1, 1, 1),
       (2, 1, 2),
       (3, 1, 2),
       (4, 2, 3),
       (5, 3, 3);
```

query:

```
SELECT p.name AS project_name, m.mention AS mention_name, p.id as pid, m.id as mid, m.relation
FROM projects p
JOIN project_mentions pm ON p.id = pm.projectid
JOIN mentions m ON pm.mentionid = m.id;
```

| project_name | mention_name | pid | mid | relation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project 1 | book | 1 | 1 | 1,2 |
| project 1 | magazine a | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| project 1 | magazine a | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| project 2 | magazine v | 2 | 3 | 2,3 |
| project 3 | magazine v | 3 | 3 | 2,3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R5Sxweyg)

With the assumed model names of Project, Mention, ProjectMention

```
Project.belongsToMany(Mention, { through: ProjectMention });
Mention.belongsToMany(Project, { through: ProjectMention });
```

Then a query such as this is possible:

```
const result = await Project.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Mention,
        through: {
            model: ProjectMention
        }
    }]
});
```